# Array Indexing HighArray and HighArrayApp?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

```
public int find(long searchKey) 
{

    int j;
    for(j=0; j<nElems; j++) {  // for each element,
        if(a[j] == searchKey)     // found search value?
            return j;                // then exit loop before end (exits entire function)
    }
    // reached end of for loop
    return nElems;             // thus, can't find it
} // end find()
public void insert(long value) 
{
    a[nElems] = value;
    nElems++; 
}
```

I am trying to implement this funtion to return the index of the search key, not the value of the search key.  here is the main class that i cannot get to display the index

```
int searchKey = 33; // search for item
    int indexToDisplay = j
    if( arr.find(searchKey) )
        System.out.println("Found " + searchKey + " at index: " + j );
    else
        System.out.println("-1");
```

Comment: Why are you saying `if (arr.find(searchKey))`?  That'll be true for any non-zero value, unless we're looking at two different methods.  Also, you say that you can't get it to display the index; what does it display instead? The wrong index? -1?

Comment: What is the output right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int searchKey = 33; // search for item
int indexToDisplay = j
if( arr.find(searchKey) )
    System.out.println("Found " + searchKey + " at index: " + j );
else
    System.out.println("-1");
```

You're setting indexToDisplay equal to nothing really, what you want to do is set it to the return value of your find() method, so like this:

```
int indexToDisplay = arr.find(searchKey);
```

Then since your find method doesn't return a boolean you can do a check to see if it's a valid index in your array like this:

```
if(indexToDisplay != -1)
    System.out.println("Found " + searchKey + " at index: " + j );
```

and I'm not really sure what nElems is, but if you can't find what you're looking for in your array I would recommend returning -1.  So altogether we have something like this:

```
public int find(long searchKey) 
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<nElems; j++) {  // for each element,
        if(a[j] == searchKey)     // found search value?
            return j;                // then exit loop before end (exits entire function)
    }
    // reached end of for loop
    return -1;             // thus, can't find it
} // end find()
public void insert(long value) 
{
    a[nElems] = value;
    nElems++; 
}
```

and we call it like this:

```
int searchKey = 33; // search for item
int indexToDisplay = arr.find(searchKey);
if(indexToDisplay != -1)
    System.out.println("Found " + searchKey + " at index: " + indexToDisplay );
else
    System.out.println("-1");
```